# Appending user input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML structure, which cannot be changed.

I need to append the user typed info to a `<ul>` list with jQuery.
I have tried it using the following code but id does nothing. What would be the correct way to do it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn btn-outline-primary").click(function() {
    let toAdd = $("input[#title]").val();
    $("<li>" + toAdd + "</li>").appendTo("<ul>");
  });
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <h2>Add Show</h2>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Show Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="enter title" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="rating">Show rating </label>
            <input type="number" min="0" max="10" value="5" class="form-control" id="rating" />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Add show</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <h2> Show List</h2>
        <ul>
        </ul>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary"> Delete List</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `$("input[#title]")` is invalid selector. Also need to prevent form submit default process. You are probably seeing page reload each time but didn't mention that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bunch of bugs to fix:

- Separating selectors with space means that the document is searched for the first selector with a descendant of the second selector - you don't want that here, keep the class names together (or just select the `btn-outline-primary` alone, since there's only one of them)
- You need to `preventDefault()` to keep the form from submitting and replacing the page
- The existing `ul` in the HTML should be selected if you want to append to it - `'<ul>'` isn't a valid selector.
- The `#title` should just be selected as `#title` (`id`s can't be repeated in HTML, after all):

```js
$(".btn-outline-primary").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let toAdd = $("#title").val();
  $("<li>" + toAdd + "</li>").appendTo("ul");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <h2>Add Show</h2>
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Show Title</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="enter title" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="rating">Show rating </label>
          <input type="number" min="0" max="10" value="5" class="form-control" id="rating" />
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Add show</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <h2> Show List</h2>
      <ul>
      </ul>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary"> Delete List</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    let toAdd = $("#title").val();
    $("<li>" +toAdd+ "</li>").appendTo(jQuery("ul"));
  });
});
```

1. First override the submit.
2. Value should be fetched properly. using `#title`
3. Append to proper element

Comment: Hi, tried doing it your way and it worked like a gem, but tell me, if I wanted to reset the form after clicking on the Add Show button, where would I do it? outside the code you wrote? or could I just nest it inside?

Comment: Inside the submit.. nest it inside

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong selectors in your code (for btn and title), plus i'd change also the append code.
Also, you have a submit button inside a form, clicking it will cause the submit.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(e){
        //prevent form submit;
        e.preventDefault();

        //append input text value to UL
        $("ul").append("<li>" + $("#title").val() + "</li>");
    });
});
```

[Click here to test if in JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Evolutionlab/jt68nfkq/)